# Replace email domain for the guest accounts in Azure AD

Tags: azure-powershell

I am looking to replace email domain (suffix after @) for the guest users in Azure AD via Powershell. As an example, i need to change email address for jdoe from jdoe@abc to @jdoe.xyz

I tried below command but it is not working.

Get-AzureADUser | where {$*.UserType -eq 'Guest' -and $*.mail -match "@abc.com"} |
ForEach-Object  { Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $($_.ObjectId) -MailNickName "abc@xyz" }

The above might be an incomplete command. Someone suggest what would be the right approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to Replace email domain for the guest accounts in Azure AD using Powershell:**

To change the email domain for user accounts that have the account type "guest" in Azure Ad using Powershell, you can use below script.

1. Connect to **Azure AD** using **`connect-AzureAd`** cmdlet.
2. Use the below cmdlet to retrieve the user accounts the have account type **"guest"**

Get-AzureAdUser -Filter "accountEnabled eq true and userType eq'Guest'"

[image]

**Full PowerShell Script**

```
Install-Module AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD
$guestAccounts = Get-AzureAdUser -Filter "accountEnabled eq true and userType eq 'Guest'"
foreach ($guestAccount in $guestAccounts) {
$newUPN = $guestAccount.UserPrincipalName.Replace("@olddomain.com","@newdomain.com")
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $guestAccount.ObjectId -UserPrincipalName $newUPN
}
Get-AzureAdUser -Filter "accountEnabled eq true and userType eq 'Guest'"
```

User **UserPrincipal** domain changed successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! only difference i found is it is changing UPN but i am looking to change email address.

Comment: Only problem i am getting in that is when i am trying to set email, it is not taking -mail or -mailnickname. Below is the code i am trying

$guests = Get-AzureAdUser -Filter "accountEnabled eq true and userType eq 'Guest'" | where {$_.mail -match "@abc.com"}
foreach ($guestAccount in $guestAccounts) {
if ($guestAccount.Mail -like "*@abc.com*"){
$newemail = $guestAccount.mail.Replace("@abc.com","@contoso.com")
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $guestAccount.ObjectId **-MailNickname** $newemail
}
}

Comment: Try the below Cmd to change the Guest users Email address.

foreach ($guest in $guestUsers) {
    $guest.Mail = "<new-email>$($guest.Mail.Split("@")[1])"
    Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $guest.ObjectId -Mail $guest.Mail
}

Comment: Is it working for you? I am getting same error - "Invalid value specified for property 'mailNickname' of resource...Seems like it not accepting **-Mail** in set-azureaduser command let.

Comment: nvm.. its working with MSGraph command let. Thanks for your help.